# Expression of $\tan(\pi-2\beta)$ as a function of $\alpha$

Tags: geometry

[image]

We're given a unit circle with center $O$, together with points $C$ and $E$ through which tangent lines pass. If $\angle DOK = \alpha$ and $\angle ADO = \beta$, how can we express $\tan(\pi-2\beta)$ as a function of $\alpha$?

I started off with realizing

$$\tan(\pi-2\beta) = \tan(-2\beta) = -\tan(2\beta) = -\frac{2\tan(\beta)}{1-\tan^2(\beta)}$$

From $\angle DCO = \angle AEO = \frac{\pi}{2}$, I see that $\angle CDE = \alpha$, $\angle ABD = \frac{\pi}{2}+\alpha$ but I am not sure how helpful these are.

Comment: Careful: $\tan$ has a period of $\pi$, therefore $\tan(\pi-2\beta)=\tan(-2\beta)=-\tan(2\beta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach:

$\underline{\text{Claim that} ~\overline{OA} = \overline{OD}}.$

Based on the claim,

$$\triangle OAD ~~\text{is isosceles} ~~\implies $$

$$\angle OAD = \angle ODA = \beta \implies 2\beta + \left[ ~\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha ~\right] = \pi \implies $$

$$\pi - 2\beta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \implies 
\tan\left( ~\pi - 2\beta ~\right) = 
\tan\left( ~\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha ~\right) = \cot(\alpha).$$

---

$\underline{\text{Proof of Claim}}$

Easiest to use Cartesian coordinates.

Set points $~O,~F, ~C~$ to the coordinates $~(0,0), ~(1,0), ~(0,1), ~$ respectively.

Since $~\overline{OE} = 1,~$ point $~E~$ has a $~y~$ coordinate of $~\sin(\alpha),~$ and point $~D~$ has a
$~y~$ coordinate of $~1,~$ you must have that

$$\overline{OD} = \overline{OE} \times \frac{1}{\sin(\alpha)} = \frac{1}{\sin(\alpha)}.$$

Further, right $~\triangle AOE,~$ has a leg $~\overline{OE} = 1,~$ and $~\angle AOE = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \alpha.$

Therefore, $~\overline{OA} = ~$ the hypotenuse of $~\displaystyle\triangle AOE = 
\frac{1}{\cos\left[ ~\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha ~\right]} 
= \frac{1}{\sin(\alpha)}.$

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following relations:

1. $\frac{1}{OD} = \sin\alpha$
2. $OD = 1 + ED$
3. $AE = \tan\alpha$
4. $\frac{AE}{ED}=\tan\beta$

From these you should be able to find $\tan\beta$ as a function of $\alpha$.